# numpy: why don't my arrays have the same size after applying a mask intersection?

Tags: numpy, masked-array

When I run `.compressed()` to turn a MaskedArray into a normal ndarray there are two fewer items. Any ideas why this could be?

```
mask_intersection = np.ma.mask_or(p_data.astype("float64"), cr_data.astype("float64"))

ipdb> mask_intersection.shape
(178, 163)
ipdb> p_data.shape
(178, 163)
ipdb> cr_data.shape
(178, 163)

ipdb> p_data[mask_intersection].flatten().size
16579
ipdb> cr_data[mask_intersection].compressed().size
16579
ipdb> mask_intersection.sum()
16579
ipdb> p_data[mask_intersection].compressed().size
16577 <-- wtf??
```

no `nan`s

```
ipdb> np.argwhere(np.isnan(cr_data[mask_intersection]))
array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=int64)
ipdb> np.argwhere(np.isnan(p_data[mask_intersection]))
array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=int64)
```

Here is a copy of `p_data` https://filebin.net/ua0rn59wl1c2txac

```
import pickle
p_data = pickle.load(open("./p_data.obj", 'rb'))
```

hmm this is also strange

```
ipdb> p_data[mask_intersection].shape
(16579,)
```

am I applying the mask intersection correctly? I don't mind ending up with a 1d ndarray but the shape-transformation is a little unexpected

ooo interesting... not sure what this means

```
ipdb> cr_data[mask_intersection].mask.sum()
0
ipdb> p_data[mask_intersection].mask.sum()
2
```

I wonder if what is happening is that `p_data.mask` is old so I need to do

```
p_data_smaller = p_data[mask_intersection]
p_data_smaller.mask = False
```

or maybe I need to do

```
p_data.mask = mask_intersection
```

instead

Comment: Will you please share a sample dataset?

Comment: I know `R` has `dput()` is there something similar in python to copy variables into pastebin? maybe I'll try `pickle.dumps()`

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jakso `print(df.head(10).to_dict())`

Comment: Hmmm, @fakso I'm not able to visit the URL linked at the end of your post. It says `AccessDenied`.

Comment: hmm maybe direct link doesn't work. does it load now?

Comment: I also added the mask_intersection to the same filebin thing as `mask.obj`

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to overwrite the ma.mask instead of subsecting the ndarray.

```py
# copy nodata from both rasters and intersect
mask_intersection = np.ma.mask_or(p_data.mask, cr_data.mask)
# flatten into 1d ndarray (not MaskedArray)
p_data.mask = mask_intersection
cr_data.mask = mask_intersection
p_data_c = p_data.compressed()
cr_data_c = cr_data.compressed()
```